# configure routing of POST parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, parameters

Do the POST parameters need some sort of routing configuration in ASP.NET MVC? If I write a method in my controller:
DoSomething(bool DoItRightNow)
and then pass in the POST parameters the DoItRightNow value, then will it work?
Also, in what format the POST parameters should be for MVC to understand them? Is JSON going to be understood by MVC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do the POST parameters need some sort of routing configuration in ASP.NET MVC?

No.

> If I write a method in my controller: DoSomething(bool DoItRightNow) and then pass in the POST parameters the DoItRightNow value, then will it work?

Yes.

> Also, in what format the POST parameters should be for MVC to understand them?

`application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`

> Is JSON going to be understood by MVC?

Out of the box in ASP.NET MVC 3 and [a bit of a coding](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx) in previous versions.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer! I am using MVC 2 (from what I've seen in the config file), so I need to make sure that JSON is interpreted alright in my project.